# Writing in txt file on AS3 - 1120: Access of undefined property FileMode

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, file-writing

I am trying to write in `.txt` file using AS3, but unfortunately I can't compile the code. I followed several tutorials and I couldn't fix my problem. If it's possible help me.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

stop();

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadComplete);

function  loadComplete(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var file:File = File("test.txt")
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    //stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.open(file,FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes("This is my text file.");
    stream.close();

 }
```

The error I am receiving is "`1120: Access of undefined property FileMode.`". Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You simply forgot to `import flash.filesystem.FileMode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shown you because You doesn't import `FileMode` class.

```
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
```

*Note :* Adobe AIR version only supports `File, in my knowledge.

1. If you want write your `test.txt` file without any prompt

> ```
> var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt"); var
>  stream:FileStream = new FileStream();    
>  stream.open(file,FileMode.WRITE); stream.writeUTFBytes("This is my
>  text file."); stream.close();
> ```

2. If you want to write with prompt

> ```
> import flash.filesystem.*;
> import flash.events.Event;
>
> var docsDir:File = File.documentsDirectory;
> function loadComplete(event:MouseEvent):void {
>   try {
>       docsDir.browseForSave("Save As");
>       docsDir.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, saveData);
>   } catch (error:Error) {
>       trace("Failed:", error.message);
>   }
> }
>
> function saveData(event:Event):void {
>   var newFile:File = event.target as File;
>   var str:String = "Hello.";
>   if (! newFile.exists) {
>       var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
>       stream.open(newFile, FileMode.WRITE);
>       stream.writeUTFBytes(str);
>       stream.close();
>   }
> }
> ```

[Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)

Comment: Thank you, but can I ask you a question. What does " Adobe AIR version only supports `File, in my knowledge." mean, do you think I can run that code on Android device ? And what does prompt mean. Sorry for the dump questions

Comment: Yes. You can run it on android devices. AIR will support for andriod, ios and desktop.